# Intent Service to Receive SMS and ShutDown

Tags: android, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Actually I wish to build an Intent Service to Receive SMS as you know that To perform Asynchronous task we use Intent Service. Now in my application Service listen for Incomming SMS and aftre storing it in dbase get shutdown and again when a sms incomming then it listen for sms and storing it and getting shutting down how I can do so. Pl help me in this regards. thanks in advance and sorry for my bad pronounciation if not understand..

thanks n regards

Om Prakash Kaushik..

Answer (score 1):

You need a broadcast receiver.

In your manifest you need to declare the permission;

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
```

Then declare the class to receive SMSs

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then declare your class

```
public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //intent contains SMS data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir One more question is that can we use a broadcast receiver to receive sms and save in dbase if my application is closed. how I can do so pl help me..

Comment: Sure totally. it's almost a one liner getContentResolver.insert(YoureProviderContract.CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues("sms", text). Check out vogella's tute on contentproviders http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but sir please tell me that what is the best way to use database access(Reading,writting) by the use of ContentResolver,Content Provider Or the Sqllite Open Helper pl tell me which method increase performance time of the application.. thanks

Comment: The link provided from vogella goes through the whole contentresolver, contentprovider sqldbopenhelper chain. They all work together.

Comment: it would be appreciated if you could accept the answer if it is accurately triggering on sms receive.